# HTTP live Streaming reader

Tags: html

I have a server providing live streaming channel over a network via http and upd (http://..., upd://...), and I've been trying to find a way to display the stream to users in their browser (on at least Windows 7). I have tried to set video tag  with src "**http:// ip of server - ip of channel**...", but i have obtained that "**video format or MIME type is not supported**".

so i have tried to save this content for 1 min and then played as a normal video, it's played normaly. So i think that my problem is to find  a solution to display this content on the browser.

kindly, can you help me to find this solution or the steps and the tools required for this issue.  please.

best regards,